# Format string with list in Python3

Tags: string, python-3.x, format

Lets say I have string: `s = '{1} goes to {0}'`

And I want to format this string with list: `l = ['Hollywood', 'Frankie']`

I cannot modify string and list both. Is there way to write simple piece of code to handle this case?

PS. I know about question "Python Format String with List", but it is not what Im asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the unpack operator `*` when passing the list to the `format` method.

```
s = '{1} goes to {0}'
l = ['Hollywood', 'Frankie']
print(s.format(*l))
```

This outputs:

```
Frankie goes to Hollywood
```